# How to search for an attribute amongs multiple tables

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I need to know how to search for an attribute among multiple tables in terminal. Is there any such command in sqlite3 for this purpose?

Comment: Best to stick to tagging a single DBMS.  Is your question about postgresql or sqlite?  And what attribute are you searching for and what have you tried?

Comment: I want to do this in terminal. How can I do it?

Comment: I removed the "postgresql" tag because the question is explicitly about SQLite.

Comment: Do you know the answer?

Comment: What do you mean with "attribute"? Column name, or data value?